# Error adding multiple records MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

i'm trying to add multiple textbox values to database it is working on just single textbox row but now working when i'm adding multiple rows of textboxes. i'm sharing what i have done so far.

Action Method:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(FormCollection values)
{
    var customer = new Customer();
    var model = new TicketViewModel();
    TryUpdateModel(model.TicketDetail);

    try
    {
        foreach (var ticket in model.Tickets)
        {
            ticket.Date = DateTime.Now;
            ticket.ProcessId = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString().Substring(12, 6);
            ticket.CreationMethod = "Manual";
            ticket.isCustomer = User.IsInRole("Customer") ? true : false;
            ticket.Total = 0;
            ticket.Email = model.TicketDetail.Ticket.Email;

            customer.City = "Not Specified";
            customer.Country = "Not SPecified";
            customer.Image = "~/Images/nopic.jpg";
            customer.Password = System.Web.Security.Membership.GeneratePassword(11, 3);
            customer.IsActive = true;
            customer.CreationMethod = "Manual";
            customer.DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
            customer.Email = ticket.Email;
            customer.FirstMidName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(ticket.FullName) ? "Not Specified" : ticket.FullName;
            customer.LastName = "Not Specified";
            customer.Salutation = "Not Specified";
            customer.UserName = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString().Substring(3, 9);

            //ticket detail
            var abcd = values["abcd"].ToString();
            var getID = await db.Parts.Where(c => c.PartNumber == abcd)
                                      .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            model.TicketDetail.GenericOrderId = ticket.GenericOrderId;
            model.TicketDetail.PersonID = customer.PersonID;
            model.TicketDetail.Status = "New";
            model.TicketDetail.PartId = getID.PartId;
            model.TicketDetail.Ticket.Date = DateTime.Now;
        }

        try
        {
            //   db.Tickets.Add(ticket);
            db.Customers.Add(customer);
            db.TicketDetails.Add(model.TicketDetail);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewBag.PartId = new SelectList(db.Parts.Take(5), "PartId", "Name");
            ModelState.AddModelError("", string.Format(ex.Message + "\n" + ex.InnerException));

            return View(model.TicketDetail);
        }

        // Save all changes
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

        ModelState.AddModelError("", String.Format(ex.Message + "\n" + ex.InnerException));
        //Invalid - redisplay with errors
        return View(model.TicketDetail);
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class TicketViewModel
{
    public TicketViewModel()
    {
        TicketDetails = new List<TicketDetail>();
        TicketDetail = new TicketDetail();
        Ticket = new Ticket();
        Tickets = new List<Ticket>();
    }
    public virtual Ticket Ticket { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }

    public virtual TicketDetail TicketDetail { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<TicketDetail> TicketDetails { get; set; }
}
```

it is also giving error on this "TryUpdateModel(model.TicketDetail);" the error is value cannot be null, please guide me i'm stuck here i have searched internet but couldn't found any appropriate solution. i want to add multiple records

Comment: The property of your TicketViewModel class TicketDetail seems to be not initialized/ assigned and therefore it is null... Use a constructor to initialize the property!

Comment: thanks for the comment, how i can solve this issue? i want to add multiple texboxes records into the database

Comment: You need to add a constructor to your TicketViewModel which creates an instance of TicketDetail

Comment: this.TicketDetails = new List<TicketDetail>(); like this?

Comment: Correct :)But wait it must be this. TicketDetail = new TicketDetail(); Just to solve this particular problem. But you better initialize all properties of your view model class.

Comment: thanks i have added like this, but how i can post multiple values to database?

Comment: If you still have problems, post the actual error message.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for the comment the problem is it is not sending values to foreach loop, i have debug the code and found that the list count is ZERO., how i can solve this?

Comment: Look at the request by pressing F12 in Chrome. Do the values that need to be inserted appear there? If not post the code of the view in the question.

Comment: @MalcolmFrexner i have checked the values are there, the issue is the loop is not executing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First all properties of your `TicketViewModel` class have to be instantiated.

To add multiple records (multiple Insert) you could use a StringBuilder and append the insert statements to it. You then have one big query string to be executed on your database.

If using values this is also a valid way:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

And loading the data to be inserted directly from a file is even faster.

**Edit**
(after down voting for no reason)
Because some people act like they know it all:

SQL injections are indeed a serious problem when dealing with Database access. That's no secret at all. A common technique to prevent the SQL query from being 'highjacked' you simply use the `SQLCommand.Parameters` property which is used to map each value individually to the statement to separate the query statement from the data (values) this way. It's now impossible to inject or manipulate statements whithout breaking them. And server side validation is standard to obtain maximum security as well as escaping special input characters and avoiding the use of privilegs with no or low restrictions.

This is NOT a wrong answer.

Comment: Constructing statements by hand just asks for a SQL injection attack. Besides, the OP is using an ORM which can create the statements automatically.

Comment: Yeah, but this not easily possible when using command.Parameters options! Did you down vote this? Reverse it!

Comment: @BionicCode the problem is it is not sending values to foreach loop, i have debug the code and found that the list count is ZERO., how i can solve this?

Comment: @Usama Have you initialized the complete TicketViewModel? Have you assgined a collection to TicketViewMode.Tickets?

Comment: @Usama When accessing the TicketsViewModel the way it is declared and without modifying or assigning anything to it it remains kind of unset because all properties are not instantiated or initialized.

Comment: @BionicCode i have updated my viewmodel in my question, please check this is what i have changed now, and still getting the count zero, the loop is not executing

Comment: @Usama Ok, all object are instantiated now. But you never added any value to the list, do you? No wonder why count says 0.

Comment: @BionicCode i'm getting the values from the view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55194/discussion-between-usama-and-bioniccode).